# Результат веб-поиска сайт Wordpress

Tags: seo

Может кто знает как сделать такой результат поиска как на примере netflix? Чтобы при поиске моего сайта отображались страницы которые есть на моем сайте как на примере. Сайт на Wordpress. Плагин seo установлен Yoast SEO.

[image]

Comment: Они генерируются автоматически самим гуглом https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334